# Best way to free up memory when the android application is in background

Tags: android

We have an Android application and for device Oppo, the memory usage ranges from 200 - 300 MB. But as soon as the application goes to background, within a few minutes the process is killed and thus our app never receives any notification when it is in the background. To solve this problem, the Oppo team suggested to bring down the memory usage below 50MB when the app is in the background. What is the best approach to free up all the memory by not killing the process?

Comment: `thus our app never receives any notification when it is in the background`. there's **more** wrong with just memory usage. Why does retrieving notification rely on whether or not your app is active? That's bad practice. Instead, make it so that you can retrieve notifications even when the app is closed.

Comment: This practice is followed by Oppo. If the app process is killed, then they won't deliver notifications. And they kill the app process based on the memory available in the background. They are claiming that if we bring down the memory down to 50 MB, they will keep the process alive for 24 hours.

Comment: otherwise they'll kill the app process within 10-15 minutes

Comment: Step #1: Figure out where this memory is being used. Step #2: Figure out when and how to release it, either from a lifecycle method (e.g., `onDestroy()`) or from [`onTrimMemory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory(int)).

Comment: observe with  getMyMemoryState() along with onTrimMemory() as suggested by commonsware, and rely on push messages/ whitelist.